# Exist code handling in multi-line shell commands

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, github-actions

I have a multi-line shell command in a Makefile:

```
format:
    . $(venv_activate_path) ;\
    echo "++++++++++ ISORT ++++++++++" ;\
    isort -rc . ;\
    echo $? ;\
    echo "+++ isort status " ;\
    echo "++++++++++ BLACK ++++++++++" ;\
    black $(package_name)/ --check ;\
    echo $? ;\
    echo "+++ black package status " ;\
    black tests/ --check ;\
    echo $? ;\
    echo "+++ black test status "
```

I want this whole thing to return non-zero exist status if either of these scripts has exit code `1`. Nonetheless, I want to run all commands, regardless of whether the first fails as I call this on github actions.

The `echo $?` are all empty despite the processes (black and isort) returning exit code `1` when run individually and the `echo $?` of the entire `make format` command is `0`.
How do I get the `make format` command to return exit code 1 if at least one of these scripts has non-zero exit code?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the problem but... all of your `echo $?` statements simply print the exit status of the previous `echo` statement -- probably not what you want.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for your comment. I fixed the example. the issue persists. My question is: how do I make "make format" return non-zero exit code, when at least 1 command inside returns non-zero exit code.

Comment: Is it important for these commands to run sequentially, one after the other?  If they were run concurrently or in a different order, would that create a danger of them failing unnecessarily or having the wrong effect?

Comment: Also, is it specifically exit status 1 that you want to look for, or is it equivalent for your purposes to look for any non-zero exit status?

Comment: The very first thing you have to do is start using the escaped variable `$$?` NOT `$?`.  You want to see the _shell_ variable named `?`.  To do that you have to prevent make from treating the variable as if it were a _make_ variable: `$?` in a makefile recipe is treated by make as if it were a reference to the make variable `?`.  To see a shell variable you have to escape the `$` to "hide" it from make: `$$?`

Comment: I strongly encourage you to stop sourcing the virtualenv startup file in the Makefile.  If you insist on using virtualenv, have the user of the Makefile set it up and call `make` from within it.

Answer (score 1):

You can run both in the background and then `wait`.

This is pretty ugly as a `make` target; perhaps refactor it to a separate script.

```
format:
    . $(venv_activate_path);\
    isort -rc . & isort=$$!; \
    black $(package_name)/ --check & black=$$!; \
    wait $$isort; isortresult=$$?; \
    wait $$black; blackresult=$$?; \
    exit $$((isortresult+blackresult))
```

If these commands are rewriting the files, you will need some additional checks to force them to wait for each other. Ultimately, perhaps a better solution will be to run each separately.

(Stack Overflow renders tabs as spaces, so you will not be able to copy/paste this recipe directly.)

Comment: `wait $$isort; isortresult=$$?; wait $$black; blackresult=$$?; exit $$((isortresult+blackresult))`

Comment: Are you sure that meets the OP's requirement "I want this whole thing to return non-zero exist status if either of these scripts has exit code 1"?  The `wait` should exit with the status of the last process collected, but what if one exits with status 1 and the other with status 0?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Duh, thanks for pointing that out - updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your condition "if either of these scripts has exit code 1" can be interpreted as "if any of these commands exit with *nonzero* status", this is is a fairly clean and clear solution:

```
format:
    . $(venv_activate_path) ;\
    failed=0;\
    isort -rc . || failed=1;\
    black $(package_name)/ --check || failed=1;\
    black tests/ --check || failed=1;\
    test "$$failed" -eq 0
```

It runs the commands sequentially, using variable `failed` to track whether any command fails.  At the end, it uses the `test` command to exit with status 0 if `$failed` still has the value 0, or with a failure status otherwise.  You can restore some or all of the `echo` commands if you like, other than after the `test` command, which must be last. However, you still will not get useful information from the `$?` variable to feed to them.